# Sqlite in IONIC showing error TypeError: n.sqlitePlugin is undefined

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to IONIC and wants to do some database operations . for this I have chosen `sqlite` as database. So following tutorial  [Tutorial Link](http://nextflow.in.th/en/2015/easy-way-to-work-with-sqlite-database-in-ionic-framework/) I  wrote my `app.js` as

```
db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("nextflow.db"); //line 29

$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ta_sheets(id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, name varchar(255))");
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tas(id int primary key, name varchar(255), description TEXT, amount DECIMAL(10,2), date DATE )");
```

but somehow its not creating any database and console shows error `TypeError: n.sqlitePlugin is undefined`

```
.openDB()            ng-cordova.min.js:9
<anonymous>          app.js:29
.$get</t.ready/<()   ionic.bundle.min.js:384
r()                  ionic.bundle.min.js:22
o()                  ionic.bundle.min.js:22
```

Whats wrong  ? I am totally lost. Any help/hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: is this an error from the device or the browser?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function (ionic, $ionicPlatform) {

        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

        if (window.cordova) {
            db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "nextflow.db" }); //device
            console.log("correct");
        } else {
            db = window.openDatabase("nextflow.db", '1', 2024 * 2024 * 100, function () { }); // browser
            console.log("correct");
        }

        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ta_sheets(id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, name varchar(255))");
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tas(id int primary key, name varchar(255), description TEXT, amount DECIMAL(10,2), date DATE )");    


    });
```

And also inject ['$window','$ionicPlatform', '$cordovaSQLite'] In your App.js or controller in use.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you probably trying to execute your code from a browser. `SQLite plugin` will only work when you install on real device.

Copy paste from the tutorial you provided:

> So everything should ready now. Build the project then run this on your iOS or Android device.

Answer (score 0):

Since the SQL Lite plugin and WebSQL have the same API, I typically wrap the call to the database in a class/service and check whether I'm in a cordova app or a web browser.

```
if ( isIOSOrAndroid() ){
    return this.executeQueryDeviceInternal(query, parameters);
}
else {
   return this.executeQueryWebSql(query, parameters);
}

executeQueryDeviceInternal(query, parameters){
    return this.$cordovaSQLite.execute(this.getDatabaseConnection(), query, parameters);
}

executeQueryWebSql(query, parameters){
    var self = this;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        self.getDatabaseConnection().transaction(tx => {
            tx.executeSql(query, parameters, function(tx, results){
                resolve(results);
            }, function(transaction, error){
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    });
}
```